# "E16: Invalid range" when run command vim in terminal

Tags: original-vim, command

I run `vim -c 'vnew'` and expected it run but it raised the error E16.

What I want is auto run `:PlugInstall` when open vim but not using `VimEnter`. So I opened `vim` with `-c` flag but it didn't run.

[image]

Comment: try `vim +vnew` but `vim -c 'vnew'` should also work. What about `vim -Nu NONE -c 'vnew'`?

Comment: just `vim +vnew` works and how to run with `:PlugInstall`

Comment: `vim -c 'PlugInstall'` if the command is available on runtimepath I think.

Comment: Oh, I no what happen in here. I need to change `'` to `"`. `vim -c ":PlugInstall"` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment (need to change `'` to `"`), it seems you're on a Windows platform. On Windows, often the shell only accepts `"` as a quote character, with `'` being interpreted literally.

So, in effect, it's as if Vim is getting the `:'vnew'` command, which produces that same error you get, which you can check in Vim with:

```
:'vnew'
E16: Invalid range
```

You could split that command as:

```
: 'v new '
```

So in effect it's calling `:new` with a filename of `'`. You can try `:new '` or `:new'` and you'll see it will open a new buffer named `"'"`. It's also passing the command a mark `'v`, which works as a [range](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%5Brange%5D). But since the `:new` command doesn't take a range, you get the E16 error message, as expected.

A possible fix is to use double quotes, since those are valid on Windows:

```
vim -c "vnew"
```

Or, if there are no spaces in the command (as is the case), you can just skip quotes altogether:

```
vim -c vnew
```

Comment: where reference to learn all about this? How to combine 2 command when open vim? `vim -c ":PlugInstall | vnew"` ?

Comment: Yes, that might work... or you can use `-c` twice...